# I can't open PhpStorm for the first time after installation from snap

Tags: 18.04, snap, intellij

I was installed PhpStorm official version from Ubuntu Software using snap.

Now, When I click on PhpStorm icon nothing happens and when I use cmd and write `phpstorm`:

```
/var not root-owned 33:33
```

What can I do it? I don't have any problem with any other programs in my ubuntu.